# How to call a drawable which resides in app project from library project in android?

Tags: android, xml, resources, drawable

I would like to access drawable of app project for xml resource files from library project in android.Kindly guide me with a snippet or guidance.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define resources in the library and redefine them in the app1 and app2.

As long as the resources have the same filename, the ones defined in each app will override the ones from the lib.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this. The whole point of a library project is that it is either self-contained or it is dependent on other library projects but not the main app project.

You can have public methods in the library project that the app project can use to pass values but you shouldn't directly access variables from app project in the library project.

If you do this, the library project would be dependent on the app project and would no longer be modular, thus defeating the whole point of making it a library project in the first place.

Comment: Yes I agree upon it,but I like to create a multi app using library project.For multi app we need to make changes in drawable implementation to suit changes for different app.How can I achieve that could you help me on that.Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: so make a public method in your library project which you can call from your app project like : `public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable)` . You can call this from your app project and send it whatever drawable you need to send.